# Propagate error in function which returns tuple of int

Tags: python, cython

Here's a file `t.pyx` I've written:

```py
# cython: language_level=3

cdef int foo(val: int) except? -1:
    if val != 42:
        raise ValueError("foo")
    return 0

cpdef (int, int) bar(val: int):
    res = foo(val)
    return res, res+1
```

and here's my `setup.py` file:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize


setup(
  name = 't',
  ext_modules = cythonize('t.pyx'),
)
```

and here's my `main.py` file:

```py
from t import bar

res = bar(43)
print(res)
```

If I run

```
python setup.py build_ext -i -f
python main.py
```

then I get

```
main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.pyx", line 5, in t.foo
    raise ValueError("foo")
ValueError: foo
Exception ignored in: 't.bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.pyx", line 5, in t.foo
    raise ValueError("foo")
ValueError: foo
(2075612320, 13418336)
```

So, it didn't raise.

How can I get `bar` to raise if `foo` raises?

One "hack" I've come up with is to have `t.pyx` like this

```
# cython: language_level=3

cdef int foo(val: int) except? -1:
    if val != 42:
        raise ValueError("foo")
    return 0

cpdef int bar(val: int, ret: list[int]) except? -1:
    res = foo(val)
    ret.append(res)
    ret.append(res+1)
    return 0
```

and `main.py` like this:

```py
from t import bar

res = []
bar(43, res)
print(res)
```

Is there a better way? If `bar` only needed to be called from within Cython, then I could pass an `int` pointer and modify that - however, I need to call it from a Python script too. How can I do that?

Comment: You didn't paste the contents of the second version of t.pyx, so I can't comment on your hack solution.

Comment: oops thanks - have updated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `foo` function is returning a tuple of C integers, and cython apparently doesn't generate code for `foo` that returns a python object. You can either add `except` to `foo`, just like `bar`, or you can tell the compiler you're returning a python tuple:

```
cpdef tuple bar(val: int):
    res = foo(val)
    return res, res+1
```

With that change I get a `ValueError`, as expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nathan/Documents/cython-test/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    res = bar(43)
  File "t.pyx", line 8, in t.bar
    cpdef tuple bar(val: int):
  File "t.pyx", line 9, in t.bar
    res = foo(val)
  File "t.pyx", line 5, in t.foo
    raise ValueError("foo")
ValueError: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

There's three options:

1. You could try specifying an error tuple value

   ```
   cpdef (int, int) bar(val: int) except? (-1, -1):
      res = foo(val)
      return res, res+1
   ```

   I'm not completely sure this'll work (and not able to test it right now), but that'd certainly be the best case
2. Use `except *` (which always does the exception check, but doesn't require the ability to specify an error value). If "1" doesn't work then this is your best option.

   ```
   cpdef (int, int) bar(val: int) except *:
      res = foo(val)
      return res, res+1
   ```
3. Do what @ngoldbaum suggests and return a Python tuple instead of a C-tuple. (Cython can always generate error handling for functions returning a Python object). For the case where the function is called from Python there is no advantage to returning a C-tuple. For the case where the function is called from Cython this is probably less efficient.